# Lightning Spinner not showing up in spinner on submit

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I've got a modal that shows a confirmation page, once you hit "Submit" inside that modal, you're redirected to the saved record. I wish to add a lightning spinner to this modal just to show the user that the click on the button works, but I can't get the spinner to show up.

The button to have the modal opened up:

Markup:

```
<aura:component access="global">
<aura:attribute name="theAccountName" type="String" />
<aura:attribute name="theResourceName" type="String" />
<aura:attribute name="isDisabled" type="Boolean" default="true" />

<aura:registerEvent name="submitInformation" type="c:getSubmitBookingButton" />
<lightning:overlayLibrary aura:id="overlayLib"/>
<lightning:button class="slds-m-top_medium"
                  name="modal"
                  label="Confirm"
                  onclick="{!c.handleShowModal}"/>
```

The controller, where a button is created once the modal pops up. On that button click, it fires an event that creates and redirects the user to the record:

```
handleShowModal: function(component, event, helper) {
    var myAccount = component.get("v.theAccountName")
    var myResource = component.get("v.theResourceName")
    var modalBody;
    $A.createComponents([
        ["c:ModalContent", {
            "accountName": myAccount,
            "resourceName": myResource,
            }],
        ["lightning:button",{
            "label": "Submit",
            "onclick": component.getReference("c.fireEvent")
            }],
    ],
   function(content, status) {
       if (status === "SUCCESS") {
           modalBody = content;
           component.find('overlayLib').showCustomModal({
               header: "Confirm your booking details",
               body: modalBody,
               showCloseButton: true,
               cssClass: "mymodal",

           })
       }
   });
},

fireEvent: function(component, event, helper) {
    var event = component.getEvent("submitInformation");
    event.fire();
},
```

I listen for the event as such:

```
<aura:attribute name="showSpinner" type="Boolean" default="false"/>

<aura:handler name="getSpinner" event="c:getSpinner" action="{!c.toggleSpinner}"/>
<lightning:icon size="medium" iconName="action:approval" alternativeText="Approved" />

<aura:if isTrue="{!v.showSpinner}">
    <div class="slds-spinner_container" style="width: 100%">
        <div class="slds-spinner--brand slds-spinner slds-spinner--medium" role="alert">
            <span class="slds-assistive-text">Loading</span>
            <div class="slds-spinner__dot-a"></div>
            <div class="slds-spinner__dot-b"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</aura:if>
```

controller to set spinner to true:

```
toggleSpinner: function(component, event, helper) {
    component.set("v.showSpinner", true)
}
```

However, the spinner never shows up.. I'm just redirected to the saved record after 2ish seconds after clicking on the "Submit" button. I just want to prevent the user from clicking too many times which would essentially create more than one record.

Any advice?